# Tailwind : How to make a fixed cover image from any size of image?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

so I want to make about section with descriptions and images split into 2 columns like the image below [image: preview]

so the problem here I want make this image center and have ratio i.e 3:4 for the anything original image size. How can I do that in Tailwindcss? thankyou and sorry for my bad english

[image: code]

Answer (score 0):

To make image center, use `object-center`

For example:

```
<img class="object-center">
```

To adjust image aspect ratio to 3:4, use `aspect-[3/4]`

For example:

```
<img class="aspect-[3/4]">
```